# MVC 6 reference Jquery after adding via Nuget

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I created a new MVC 6 project, empty template. added JQuery via NuGet. How do you reference it then in your _Layout file or wherever you want to use it. I dont have a script folder with Jquery in there.

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
<script src=""></script> -- HERE

<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    @RenderBody()
</div>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Project soultion]

Comment: in asp.net 5/mvc 6 the new correct way to manage client side dependencies is using npm bower gulp and grunt, not nuget. I recommend create a new web project in vs2015 to see how it sets up jquery see also http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/index.html

Comment: Cheers, makes sense. Got it working there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the package from Nuget and add via bower. If you have created a new MVC 6 empty project. you will need to add a bower.json file and then add the Jquery   dependency

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.1.4"
 }
}
```

Then in your layout add the reference

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```