# Modifying the solution level files in an MVC 6 Project to install a new layout

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget-package, coreclr

I have an MVC 6 (ASP.NET 5) solution and I would like to have a way to easily "install" a new layout in Visual Studio 2015.

I have the following files

```
~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml 
~/Views/Shared/{NewLayoutName}/_Header.cshtml 
~/Views/Shared/{NewLayoutName}/_Footer.cshtml 
~/wwwroot/css/{NewLayoutName}.{version}.css
~/wwwroot/css/{NewLayoutName}.{version}.{theme}.css
```

An ideal solution would would backup any files that would be overwritten such as the _Layout.cshtml file and would return on an uninstall. Then the files will appear in the installed project. I should be able to create a new MVC 6 app from Visual Studio 2015 and quickly "install this layout."

I tried Nuget and Bower. I'd try Powershell but I hear that's why Nuget doesn't work.

Bower seems to only for client side packages.

I tried using Nuget Package Explorer to create the package and created every variation of folder structures (src, tools, content, "normal" folders, native).

I thought Nuget would be perfect for this but it appears Nuget can't even add css or js to an MVC 6 project. I think this is a Powershell issue.

1. [Nuget's github Open issue #1521](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1521)
2. [StackOverflow: MVC 6 reference Jquery after adding via Nuget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935952/mvc-6-reference-jquery-after-adding-via-nuget/32936261?stw=2#32936261)

Comment: I've posted a similar answer to on how to package stuff in wwwroot into class library at http://stackoverflow.com/a/36200496/455493. It may not be exactly your use case (i.e. you can't override the _Layout.cshtml easily) but may be a start. The same technique also works for Razor, when you use `.AddRazorOptions(...) ` and `options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(...))`

Comment: The issue you are facing here is, that the new nuget (or rather dnx/dotnet-cli doesn't run any powershell scripts anymore iirc (which old package manger `Install-Package` did) after package restore

Comment: Powershell was going to be my next attempt. I tried bower last night because I thought I could override the default `wwwroot/lib` folder. Apparently on the project's `.bowerrc` file is considered.